# Monkey patched PyMongo results in slow performance as compared to YCSB results

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymongo, locust

I am developing a flask application. It's a simple application with a single endpoint, index (/) for now. In my projects `__init__.py` file, before importing anything, I monkey patch all the libraries with `monkey.patch_all()`.
Here's what my `__init__.py` looks like:

```
# --- imports begin
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

from flask.json import JSONEncoder
import os
import logging
from flask import Flask
from mixpanel import  Mixpanel
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
from flask_log_request_id import RequestID, RequestIDLogFilter
from foree.helpers.py23_compatibility import TEXT_ENCODING
# --- imports end

# application objects
app = Flask(__name__)
....
```

The index route has a single DB call to a collection that is indexed with the key `phone_number` and my query looks like this: `{phone_number: 'XYZ'}`. The index route looks like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    _ = user_by_phone_number('XYZ')
    import socket
    return jsonify(message='Hello!',
            min_version=MIN_VERSION,
            max_version=MAX_VERSION,
            app_version=SERVER_VERSION,
            config_checksum=CONF_CHECKSUM,
            environment=DEPLOYMENT,
            host=socket.gethostname(),
            time=str(datetime.datetime.now()))
```

And the function `user_by_phone_number` looks like this:

```
def user_by_phone_number(phone_number):
    db['fpi_user'].find_one({'phone_number': phone_number})
```

I have a 4 core CPU with 8Gb ram. The server is spawned with:

```
gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:18000 --access-logfile gunicorn-access.log --access-logformat '%(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s Time: %(T)s' -w 9 --worker-class gevent --worker-connections 1000 foree:app --log-level debug
```

I then go onto generate some load on this server using `locust`. Locust runs in distributed mode with 3 slaves and a master (2500 concurrent users with a hatch rate of 200) via `locust --no-web -c 2500 -r 200 -H https://myhost.com/ -t 2m --master --expect-slaves=3`

The test results in a very low TPS. Upon observing `mongostat`, I get a number of around ~1K ops/sec on my secondary (replica-set).

On the other hand I tried testing MongoDB with `YCSB` and surpisingly the results were somewhat good. The average ops/sec on secondary goes to around 21K. Which means the MongoDB is nont being fully utilized (in case of my app server). And yes, my database and app server are on the same network with a ping of less than `1ms` so latency can not be an issue here.

Here's how I test with YCSB:

```
./bin/ycsb run mongodb -s -P workloads/workloadc -threads 20 -p mongodb.url="mongodb://username:pass@<list-of-dbs>/DB?replicaSet=rs0&retryWrites=true&readPreference=secondary&localThresholdMS=30&maxPoolSize=5000" -p operationcount=10000000
```

I also tried adding New Relic to my code to find out what's causing the issue and it also complains about the PyMongo's `find_one` function that I am calling on the index route. Here's the snap:

[image]

I have been trying to figure this out for around 3-4 days without any luck. Any leads on what could possibly be wrong here would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: For instance, are you maybe setting up and tearing down a connection to the MongoDB server for each request? That'd kill your performance, and you'd want connection pooling instead (https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/faq.html#how-does-connection-pooling-work-in-pymongo).

Comment: Also, which WSGI application server are you running this with?

Comment: @AKX the DB connection is created only once in the sub-module called `database/__init__.py`

Comment: And you're absolutely positive you get a better RPS if you simply edit out that call to `get_by_phone_number()`? Because otherwise I'd suggest also moving out that call to `socket.gethostname()` outside the function...

Comment: Yes, gives me a boost of approx 250 TPS.

Comment: @AKX I am using `gunicorn`

Comment: If you get 250 TPS from not doing anything with Mongo, how much is the original "very low TPS"?

Comment: @AKX I mean without the DB call, I get more that/close to 1000 TPS, Enabling this call, results in a drop to 750-770 TPS approx.

Comment: What I am worried about is this single call resulting in a massive degradation. If add 2-3 more database calls to the same collection, that would certainly drop even further.

Comment: Have you tried that? `for x in range(5): user_by_phone_number('XYZ')`

Comment: Just tried it and the average TPS dropped to `521.63`

Comment: Alright. Well, I'd next try to replicate these results in an environment you can run a profiler in (i.e. locally, against a development MongoDB, using e.g. the flask test client in a loop) and figure out what the hotspots are using one. I think gevent is a red herring here.

Comment: @AKX Just one more piece of information... I forgot to tell, the collection contains around 65K records.

Comment: If your YCSB test is doing an equivalent query as your app is and is that much faster, that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Not exactly that query. I ran the test on YCSB's `workloadc` which is all reads. I believe YCSB creates its own collection and inserts the new records.

Comment: So that's not really an equivalent benchmark at all. Either way, you're going to need a profiler to figure out what's going on here.